livewire 3 | how to use more than one layouts?
i want to create more than one layouts in my application, but the 2nd layout(app-without-header) which i have created giving me this error
layouts folder structure shown below

when i attached this new "layout app-without-header" with my child component it's giving me error
child component Detail.php file code below
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Product;

use App\Services\ProductService;
use Livewire\Attributes\Layout;
use Livewire\Component;

class Detail extends Component
{
    public $slug;
    public $product;

    function mount(ProductService $product_service) {
       $this->product = $product_service->getProductDetail($this->slug);
    }

    #[Layout('layouts.app-without-banner')]
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.product.detail');
    }
}

any one can help me?

As you can see in Livewire documentation, layouts is relative to views folder, not views/components.
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/components#layout-files
So if you want to store your layouts inside components folder, you should modify the path to your layout file:
#[Layout('components.layouts.app-without-banner')]


thanks. it's worked.
